# Tapku Calendar Events

Tags: iphone, xcode, eventkit, tapku

Iam newbie with this calendar sort of thing...Please suggest me if possible.

Iam using Tapku calendar.And i want to add events that will sync with tapku calendar.
Is that possible..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the Sqlite database and store those events in database.And whenever you are getting approached the event dates then you can fire the localnotifications